# How to import data from a .DBF file into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, foxpro, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter, oledbdatareader

So far I have a successful connection retrieving data from a `.dbf` file but I can not figure out how to store this data into my database. Currently I have my connection with SQL Server and connection string name is  `PortageleafPickupEntities1` which holds three columns Address, SeasonType, and NextPickupdate.

Now this `.dbf` data has all the data for each column just got to tranfer it there.

Here is the code...

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]LeafPickup pickup )
{
    string cadena = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\azib\\Desktop\\dfb; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID = Admin; Password =";
    string select = "Select * from sp18br ";

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cadena);
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(select, con);
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

    con.Open();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "sp18br");
    con.Close();

    DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;

    foreach (DataTable dt in dta)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found data table {0}", dt.TableName);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} rows in sp18br table", myDataSet.Tables["sp18br"].Rows.Count);

    DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables["sp18br"].Rows;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
    {
        // Print the CategoryID as a subscript, then the Name:
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + " {0} -- {1} -- {2} -- {3} -- {4} ", "\n" + dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4]);
    }

    using (PortageLeafPickupEntities1 entities = new PortageLeafPickupEntities1())
    {
        entities.LeafPickups.Add(pickup);
        entities.SaveChanges();

        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, pickup);
        message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + pickup.ID.ToString());
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's back up a minute and ask a more basic question.   Is this a One-Time IMPORT of data (as your title suggests) or does this need to be an Active, Live, On-Going connection?   The answer to that very likely may guide our advice.

Comment: Good question. No, it will not be an on going connection consistently. Just opening the connection taking the data and closing the connection off.

Comment: For a One-time Import you might want to do a Google search for:  vfp upsizing    Some of the more recent, updated versions (The Sedna release) of this VFP tool might work better than the original ones.  If that works for you, your code will be largely unnecessary.